# Access 2010 Error Accessing the system registry

Tags: ms-access

Somehow I have an invalid reference in the VBA code of my Access 2010 application.  When I try to go to Toots, References I get an error message "Error accessing the system registry".

I am running Windows 7

Comment: There is a KB http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269383

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling Windows and the problem was resolved.  Unfortunately I never resolved the reason this was happening.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Windows 7 too and solved this error with the "User Account Control Settings", and then chose "Never Notify" about changes in my computer!

[User Account Control Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlexA.png)